# CiviCRM API v4 didn't recognized php variable

Tags: apiv4

I was new to CiviCRM, I have the following where %search is a variable in the php, it didn't return anything, is it true that cannot passed parameter in this way? Thanks

$contacts = civicrm_api4('Contact', 'get', [
'select' => [
'id',
'display_name',
],
'where' => [
['OR', [['id', 'CONTAINS', $search], ['display_name', 'CONTAINS', $search]]],
],
'limit' => 25,
]);

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a permissions issue. By default anonymous doesn't have access to contacts, so you either need to add `'checkPermissions' => FALSE` to the parameters or run it as a logged in user with appropriate permissions.